# How to add css style/class to a HtmlTextWriterTag.Td dynamically in .net?

Tags: c#, css, dynamic, rendercontrol

I have the following c# code in my control's RenderContents method. How can I add the style/class that is in external css file?

```
output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Border, "0");
output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, "100%");
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tbody);
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
//Here -> Need to add some style from external stylesheet.css file
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
rblLoadSelection.RenderControl(output);
output.RenderEndTag(); //Td
output.RenderEndTag(); //Tr
output.RenderEndTag(); //Tbody
output.RenderEndTag(); //Table
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reference an external stylesheet between a `td` and `tr`. The best place to put it is in the `head` tag of your document.

Based on your comments, if you just need to add a class to `td`, do this:

```
output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "myclass");
```

Comment: I think he wants to add a style, or class attribute to the TD element, not a link to a stylesheet (I think).

Comment: yes, I just need to add a style/class to TD. Sorry for the not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can include external CSS (without including it in head and use classes) or do it inline like this:

```
output.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "#000000");
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
```

Comment: I need to add the css style class to td not add an external css file.